# Laravel runtime exception (1/1)

Tags: php, laravel

I get this message when trying to enter localhost/lsapp/public
https://ibb.co/gWWyhvx

Comment: did you run the `php artisan key:generate` command?

Comment: Have you tried googling? Refer to this issue here, you'll find your solution: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/9080

Answer (score 0):

you must enable Mcrypt Extension 
extension=php_mcrypt.dll
[link](https://www.corrensa.com/how-to-enable-php-mcrypt/)

and run below code

```
php artisan key:generate
```